# Multiple RelativeSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I have a need in a DataTemplate to have my binding going to potentially 2 different types of RelativeSource ie something like this:

```
AllowDrop={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Label} or AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=AllowDrop}
```

In this case the relativeSource will look up the tree and find the first ancestor of type Label or TextBlock. Now I know what you're all going to say, "Why the heck to you want to do something stupid like that for??" Fair question, I'm glad you asked :-) The reason is that I am using the WPFish grid from syncfusion. I say WPFish because whoever wrote it didn't have a clear understanding of how WPF should work and it requires quite a few hacks to get it to work as it should. One of the hacks I need to set AllowDrop of a ContentControl in my template to be the same as the AllowDrop property on their grid. Normally this would be a fairly simple matter of just binding with a RelativeSource type of their grid, but they have 2 grids. One is called GridControl and the other GridDataControl. So I need to search up the tree to find the first control of type GridControl or GridDataControl and grab the AllowDrop property from that.

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: I think the TemplateParent in this case won't be the grid. It's only for ControlTemplates isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Binding Converter and bind to the element itself and then walk the visual tree in the binding converter to find the element you want.....uuugggglllyyy!!

`{Binding Path=., RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource findTheCorrectParentConverter}`}

and some code in your converter like so:

```
DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
while(!(parent is TextBox|| parent is Label)){
   parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
}

if (parent != null){
   //do some stuff with your stuff.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aran, that is pretty much exactly the solution I am currently using. You came up with that quickly, it took me a lot longer :-) As you say it is very ugly, I was hoping for something like {Binding RelativeSource={MultipleRelativeSource Type1=.... etc. At least then the new MarkupExtension is reusable.

Comment: could you create your own markup extension to do the job? (never done this myself) I would be interested in seeing an elegant solution.

Comment: I did look into this. It was fairly easy to write (just inherit from MarkupExtension) and the override ProvideValue is called by WPF, all I need to do is return the correct control. The problem is that all I have is the binding so I couldn't work out how to get the control from there. It's probably not too difficult but that's were I got stuck. I probably need to start a new question, "How do you find the target from a binding object" :-)

Comment: provide a link if you do, be interested to follow along. cheers

Comment: I had a look into it by trying to create a markup extension to completely replace the binding. This would work fine for an example that used a textbox/combobox as the 2 parents. ProvideValue was called and I could easily get to the target. I thought I had it solved. But when I used it with the grid I got an object called a SharedDp which only had 3 properties, all of which are null. Life is too short to go into this further so I will mark your response as the answer. This is just a one-time hack to get around a limitation in the grid so it's not something I need to repeat everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you put both `Label` and `TextBox` inside a `ContentView`, then, you can set your `RelativeSource` to the `ContentView`, i.e.

Your `Binding.Path` changes from `AllowDrop` to `Content.AllowPath` where `Content` will either be the `Label` or the `TextBox`:

```xml
AllowDrop={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentView}},
                   Path=Content.AllowDrop}
```

If you are worried about false positives from other components using `ContentView`, then, you can consider subclassing the `ContentView`, say `LabelTextBoxContentView` then, you know the `RelativeSource` will never pick up false positives by looking for this specific type.